# Eclipse RCP e4 using cached version of Application.e4xmi file

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4, xmi

So I'm writing e4 RCP application for my studies. My problem is that, as I change the Application.e4xmi file -  I basically add / remove some part (View) -  the **changes are not reflected** in the application later run ! It's totally as eclipse (IDE) or eclipse RCP app would cache the file or it's binary outcome (whatever it is) and is not using the new, current version.

I build, clean, remove workspace runtime location etc. but noting works. I am stuck.

```
eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-win32-x86_64
jdk1.8.0_40
```

Project was created as e(fx)clipse -> JavaFx -> OSGI -> e4 Application projects

--EDIT--

If I change plugim.xml and make product property point to a not existing file:

```
<property name="applicationXMI" value="com.budzek.herber.app/Application2.e4xmi" />
```

No exception if thrown, nor is something logged, and rcp application looks like from the old,"cached" e4xmi file.

I'd really appreciate your help, 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify the `-clearPersistedState` option in the Run Configuration for the application to stop it loading the saved e4xmi file. You might also want to use `-clean` to make sure plugin changes are also picked up.

Ypu can also specify `-persistState false` to stop the persisted state being saved on exit.

The persisted state is stored in the workspace in the '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi' file. Deleting this file (when the RCP is not running) will also reset the state.

Comment: Man, you're awesome. Btw do you know where it keeps this data ?

Comment: The persisted state is stored in the workspace in the '.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi' file. You can just get away with deleting this file.